# CSS Animation Delay for multiple divs with same class

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm working on a project where multiple div's are loaded with a small animation, but as you can see in the fiddle down, they're carrying all at once. Any idea how do they carry one after another with a delay of 0.1 s?

http://jsfiddle.net/HaQmN/38/

Thanks

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
  -o-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

.example {
    display: inline-block;
    width:48%;
    height:100px;
    background:orange;
    margin: 1% 1%;
}



<div class="animated fadeInUp example">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Which one is needed to animate first & last?

Comment: They should load from the left ro right and line by line... And yes, i know . is for class...

Comment: Are you willing to use Javascript? Because I'm not sure there would be a way to do this without JS.

Comment: They should load from the left to right line by line... And yes, i know . is for class, why?

Comment: Have not tried using javascript or jquery, I will try to do just CSS first because I'm not very good with js ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay animation with animation-delay property like bellow.

```
 .animated:nth-child(1){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.animated:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    background-color: red;
}
.animated:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.animated:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.animated:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.animated:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

But that is a lot of CSS and doest not suite if you have dynamic number of Divs. so you javascript to add delay property to you divs one by one.

Comment: Yeah, i will try to create some js script later... By the way, Thanks!

Comment: where is the script? :D

Comment: it is coming... :DD